# How to trap EXIT unconditionally (even if interrupted), in Zsh?

Tags: zsh, signals, trap

I would like to trap the exit hook of a function. Bash provides a nice signal called `RETURN` (non-POSIX) which get called when a function returns, such as

```bsh
function test_trap() {
    trap 'echo trapped' RETURN
    sleep 10  # simulate time-consuming commands
    echo done
}
```

I see “trapped” when the function returns, *even if I send a `SIGINT` with `Ctrl` `C`*. Is there similar functionality for Zsh? I tried `EXIT` in Zsh, but it only traps normal returns, not when I interrupt with `SIGINT`. I also tried trapping *both* `EXIT` and `INT` with the same hook function, but it has two issues:

1. The hook expression is evaluated twice when I interrupt it. No big deal; my hook expression happens to be idempotent.
2. The `EXIT` in Zsh is local: when returning from the function, the original hook is recovered. This is similar to how a local variable shadows a global one. Unfortunately, the `INT` hook is always global, so any hook I specify will overwrite the global one. I would need to remember the original `INT` hook, and recover it later. It’s very tricky to do it correctly; I may have a try on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's like for the EXIT trap outside of functions. Exiting and being killed are two different things.

So like outside of functions, you need to handle them separately:

```
test_trap() {
  set -o localoptions -o localtraps
  trap 'echo "I am exiting."' EXIT
  trap 'echo "I have been interrupted, so"; return 1' INT

  echo start
  sleep 10
  echo end
}

test_trap
echo "returned with: $?"
```

Which gives:

```
$ zsh ./that-script
start
^CI have been interrupted, so
I am exiting.
returned with: 1
```

If you want the *shell* (not just the function) to exit when it handles the SIGINT signal when received while executing the function, replace `return 1` with `exit` (or kill yourself with SIGINT after having restored the default handler (`trap - INT; kill -s INT "$$"`) if you want to report your death by signal to your parent).

Comment: It’s sad to hear that I still need to trap the `INT`, because I actually don’t care how the function is terminated. I’m going to simply document the assumption that `INT` trap was unset before calling the function; this assumption makes my clean-up part way easier (otherwise I would need to go [this far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115144/save-and-restore-trap-state-easy-way-to-manage-multiple-handlers-for-traps/16115145#16115145)). Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry, the first time I read this, I somehow missed the `localtraps` line. Reading it again, there is nothing to “clean up”. This is perfect solution! Thank you. One nitpick: I prefer to preserve the original return value for INT, which is 130.

Comment: @FranklinYu, 130 is the number most shells (including zsh) put in `$?` when the child process they're waiting for dies of a SIGINT, but doing `exit 130` is not the same thing as being killed by SIGINT. See [Default exit code when process is terminated?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/99112) for details. And see [How to trigger error using Trap command](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/79654) and unix.stackexchange.com/a/230568 for why it may be preferable to kill yourself with SIGINT (like I hint in the answer) than to do `exit 130` if you want to report to your parent that you've been interrupted.

Comment: Thanks for the complete guideline. Does the “`kill` better than `exit`” rule also applies to functions? In other words, is there “`kill` better than `return`”?

Comment: @FranklinYu, functions bodies are evaluated by the same shell process. So unless the function bodies is a subshell (as in `func() (echo in a subshell)`, If you kill the process that runs the function, you kill the script. That kill vs exit only matters when the waiting process behaves like bash (zsh doesn't). Inside your own script, you can do what you want based on the exit status of your function.